# How to include iOS8 extensions when using a custom share UI?

Tags: ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller

There is any way to access sharing extensions without popping the default UIActivityViewController?
I couldn't find one, but asking just in case.

In case not, i have another question. 
How are you planing to adapt your app's custom sharing interfaces to this restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access Share/Action extensions without using UIActivityViewController. In iOS8  sharing area of the activity view controller is the only entry point for share extensions.

From Apple docs.

> Each of which is tied to an area of the system, such as sharing,
>   Notification Center, and the iOS keyboard. A system area that supports
>   extensions is called an extension point. Each extension point defines
>   usage policies and provides APIs that you use when you create an
>   extension for that area. You choose an extension point to use based on
>   the functionality you want to provide.

The best you can do is to provide a share menu with two options to launch app's custom sharing interface and UIActivityViewController. Bad UX but I don't know any other way.

Comment: Question is a bit old but I ended in same conclusion. Sadly using default UIActivityViewController is mandatory to support extensions. Hope this changes in the future (but probably it won't, to respect user privacy).